# Bringing a UITableViewCell child UIImageView to front while animating

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a UITableViewCell.
In this tableviewcell, I have an UIImageView.

I want apply a CGAffineTransform to the UIImageView when I press the image.

The problem: Other items of the cell are on top of my image and I want them to be in the back when the animation occurs.

I tried things like:

```
//In the UITableViewCell

override func didMoveToWindow() {
    super.didMoveToWindow()

    superview?.superview?.bringSubview(toFront: photoView)
  }
```

but that doesn't work.

I also tried to do:

```
photoView.layer.zLocation = 10
```

but that doesn't work either.

For those wondering, the transform code looks like:

```
let scaleTransform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale)
photoView.transform = scaleTransform
```

Any idea?

Comment: maybe this? cell.contentView.bringSubviewToFront(photoView)

Comment: try like keep your imageview on top of other views in xib.

Comment: contentView.bringSubview(toFront:) doesn't work.  @SachinAmrale , I use autolayout programmatically and no, I can't do that. Because the problem here is that I m not sure that the current cell will be on top of all the others.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaking this is what you want:

*"I want apply a CGAffineTransform to the UIImageView when I press the image"* -on top of other cell's subviews- means that you should set a `UITapGestureRecognizer` for the imageView:

Your `UITableViewCell` should be similar to:

```
// your custom cell, in my case I'm calling it "TableViewCell"
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var imgView: UIImageView!
    // your other IBOutlets...

    //...

    // this flag is useful when you want to check if the imageView is tapped, you should return it to its normal transform -for example-
    private var isImageViewMovedToFront = false

    override func didMoveToWindow() {

        // adding the tap gesture
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(TableViewCell.imgViewTapped))
        imgView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        imgView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

    }

    func imgViewTapped() {
        if isImageViewMovedToFront == false {
            isImageViewMovedToFront = true

            contentView.bringSubview(toFront: imgView)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
                let scaleTransform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.2, y: 1.2)
                self.imgView.transform = scaleTransform
            }
        } else {
            isImageViewMovedToFront = false

            contentView.sendSubview(toBack: imgView)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
                let scaleTransform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)
                self.imgView.transform = scaleTransform
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The output should looks like:

- first launch:

[image]

- tapping on the cell:

[image]

- retapping on it:

[image]

Hope that helped.

Comment: That kind of help yes. I have all the code for the gesture already but my problem is the bringSubview toFront. If you have another cell for example and your image goes over that next cell (let's say you scale by a factor that makes the image bigger than your current cell), you can have other elements on top of the picture. Also if you want to reinitialize the transform, you can use the identity matrix: CGAffineTransform.identity

Comment: Basically I m trying to do something similar to the Instagram pinch to zoom into post images. I don't understand how to go through this layout issue.